# How to get the SVN revision number in certain Date or date range

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

How can I get the revision number of a branch on certain date.

I have tried :

```
svn checkout -r {2006-02-17}
```

but can't get any output.

Answer (score 15):

```
 svn co -r {2011-11-28} svn://location/of/my/repository/branch
```

works for me. May be you are missing URL.
however if I try to checkout a revision of a time when repo did not exist, I get

```
svn co -r {2006-11-28} svn://location/of/my/repository/branch
svn: Unable to find repository location for 'svn://location/of/my/repository/branch' in revision 0
```

---

**Update**
After reading your comment you seem to be just interested in seeing committed file in a date range.  Here is what I do:

```
svn log -r {2011-12-02}
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r10514 | nishant | 2011-12-01 22:47:44 +0000 (Thu, 01 Dec 2011) | 1 line

fixed issue#2993
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

refer: [SVN doc for revision specifiers](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html) *Do read why it gives results for the commits made a day earlier.*

---

**Update:**
Revision range is not applied on date.

```
svn co -r {2012-09-04}:{2012-09-14} svn://location/of/my/repository/branch
svn: Revision range is not allowed
```

*However*, if you just wanted to see the files altered between two date range. Just see the log

```
  svn log -r {2012-09-04}:{2012-09-14}
```

Comment: This is trying to check out the code. I just want to get the  revision number that is commited on that date

Comment: @Subhen updated my answer. It will show something if there is anything _actually committed_ during the date range.

Comment: @MattR updated the answer. It seems date range is not possible. However if you wanted to see all the files changes between two dates. You may write a smart shell script that `grep`s `svn log` for the date range you wanted. Hope this helps.