# Subversion date range with revisions with no date

Tags: date, svn, subtree

I have a Subversion repository, which is a mirror of a subtree accessable by our team.
The svnadmin dump was created with a account with limited access to the source repository.
The mirror was than initalised with svnadmin load.

```
svnadmin load repo < svndump 
svn propset --revprop -r0 svn:sync-from-uuid af407c0b-a50a-0410-b304-fd27f8ee8df8 %dstrepo%
svn propset --revprop -r0 svn:sync-last-merged-rev 187698 %dstrepo%
svn propset --revprop -r0 svn:sync-from-url %SourceRepo% %dstrepo%
```

The history contains a great number of revisions without paths and dates.

```
svnsync sync  %dstrepo% %SourceRepo%
```

Sync Is working

This results in great number of svn revisions looking like this

```
svn log -vl10 repo

....
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r204669 | ebenneheij | 2014-09-22 12:04:00 +0200 (ma, 22 sep 2014) | 4 lines
------------------------------------------------------------------------
....
r204570 | (no author) | (no date) | 1 line
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r204569 | (no author) | (no date) | 1 line
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r204568 | (no author) | (no date) | 1 line
```

Related: [How to get the SVN revision number in certain Date or date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428279/how-to-get-the-svn-revision-number-in-certain-date-or-date-range)
Related: http://manned.org/rsvndump/29eed607

It looks like these empty revisions are there for padding, but they are breaking the option to use a date range for revisions.

I'm trying to validate the last 30 days of commits with

```
svnadmin verify -r {`date -d '30 days ago' +%F `}:HEAD repo
```

This fails on the revisions without a date in the revprops.

> Failed to find time on revision 191375

Somehow the svnadmin dump and svnsync create empty revisions without date information.
This is causing the error I am seeing.

I tried to drop empty revisions with svndumpfilter --drop-all-empty-revs.
The problem with that solution is that svnsync won't connect anymore.
A solution I see now is to replace svnsync with svnrdump and svndumpfilter with the lastsynchronised revision stored somewhere.

Can I fill in the padded revisions with a date so the date range will work?

**Update**: added mirroring description

**Update2**: only revisions with paths visible to me contain dates

**Update3**: alternative suggestion

**Update4**: empty revisions for padding do not contain date, how to fill the date?

Comment: How was that mirror created?

Comment: Were the proper hook scripts enabled to allow revision properties (the timestamp) to be modified in the sync process? This really seems like those revprops weren't loaded, or aren't being synced properly.

Comment: The description is updated for your questions.